# Seam 3 @Transactional annotation not working in Java EE environment

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, cdi, transactional, seam3

I have a asynchronous command processor module that spins off a number of background threads that reads DB records, loads one command (CDI Bean) per record and runs the command. Arquillian tests with Weld-SE container works fine. However, when I put this in a JavaEE environment (as a JBoss Module in JBoss EAP 6.1.1) the @Transactional annotation does not take effect - the background method runs without a transaction. Hence the changes to entities never makes to the DB.

The client module that depends on this messaging module, has this in the bean.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:s="urn:java:ee"
  xmlns:t="urn:java:org.jboss.seam.transaction"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

   <interceptors>
     <class>org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor</class>
   </interceptors>
</beans>
```

I tried the trick mentioned in [Seam @Transactional annotation not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908379/seam-transactional-annotation-not-working) but that did not work.

Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: This is actually a bug in EAP 6.1.1.  Please file a support issue with RedHat.

Comment: @JohnAment - Why do you think it's a EAP bug? Seam 3 is not shipped/supported with EAP 6.

Comment: Its a problem with loading interceptors in EAP.

Comment: @JohnAment - Are you referring to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=927895

Comment: @JohnAment - RedHat support maintains that this is a Seam3/DeltaSpike issue which they will not support. Can you elaborate the issue you have encountered; possibly leading to a reproducer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your project structure, but you should consider that the beans.xml is only working in the bean archive it is in. So you have to active the Interceptor in every Bean Archive you want it to work(CDI 1.0). With CDI 1.1 you have the ability to enable an interceptor globally.